# Java SE strong cryptography for Java 7?

Tags: java, cryptography, java-7, jce

The preview release of Java 7 seems to be missing JCE package for unlimited cryptography strength. Has someone stumbled upon such?

Comment: I **think** you don't need an extra package for this any more.

Comment: Well I think I still need it, because I get the same exception as in jdk6 with no unlimited strength encryption: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: `Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 9):

You need to install the missing JCE package.

1. Locate your jre lib/security directory

   ```
   $ which java
   /usr/bin/java

   # Do this recursively till you find the java installation folder
   $ ls -la /usr/bin/java
   ```

On Linux it should be by default: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/security/

On Windows it should be by default: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security

2. Download the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)

Download for Java 6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Download for Java 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Download for Java 8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

3. Install the JCE

Extract the downloaded zip and place the two .jar files: US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar into your jre/lib/security folder.

Overwrite old files if any.