# How to enable AES256 cipher suites in java clients

Tags: java, encryption, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed [Jre 1.8 (x64)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) on a windows server 2012 R2 machine and checked the list of supported cipher suites through a simple program like this

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getDefault();
SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
String[] cipherSuites = sf.getSupportedCipherSuites();

for (String cs : cipherSuites)
    System.out.println(cs);
```

This produced the following output (note that only AES128 suites are present, AES256 is absent)

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
```

I am looking for the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 cipher suite that is listed as top priority in the [Cryptography Providers list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider).

Is there a separate package that has to be installed to get the AES256 cipher suites in java?

Comment: Have you installed the [Unlimited Strength policy files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32080161/1816580)?

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I wonder why this isn't installed by default.

Comment: yep, we can mark this as dup